# What's the most cost effective way to keep a PPL current with Ultralights?

Tags: pilot-certification, ppl, ultralight, uk

I hold an NPPL(m) - which is a UK license for Micro/Ultralights only.

I wish to "upgrade" (sadly there is no formal upgrade path) to a PPL so that on occasion, I can hire 4 seaters.

My question is, once certified, **what is the least amount of flying one can do in light aircraft to keep a PPL valid? (when combined with Ultralight flying)**

In other words, I would like to still do 90% of my flying in Microlights, but do just enough in Light Airplanes to keep the PPL valid.